# How to keep the socket connection open in Android?

Tags: android, sockets, websocket

I am using [this](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client) library for socket connection in my android application. I need to close the connection when app is not opened and open the socket connection when users opens my application. Please any one help me how to do that. Now the socket is disconnecting after 20 or 30 minutes when the app is in background. If I want to do some changes in server side let me know.

Comment: You said that you want to close the socket when your app is not opened?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Android Activity Lifecycle?](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) That link may answer you question.